# Using AdditionalMetadata in MetaData partial class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata

I have followed the example at https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation to add data annotations to MetaData.cs

I am trying to use AdditionalMetaData, so that I may pass a variable to an EditorTemplate. I've tried:

```
[AdditionalMetadata("VariableName", "VariableValue")]
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string LastName;
```

I was hoping this would be applied in a similar way to the StringLength metadata.

Do I perhaps need to modify PartialClasses.cs? Currently this associates the model and metadata classes with:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetadata))]
public partial class Student
{
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Update:*

MetaData.cs contains:

```
[AdditionalMetadata("VariableName", "VariableValue")]
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string LastName;
```

PartialClasses.cs contains:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetadata))]
public partial class Student
{
}
```

Student.cs contains:

```
public string LastName{ get; set; }
```

I would prefer not to modify Students.cs - as I may need to regenerate this in the future. I had hoped to add the AdditionalMetaData in MetaData.cs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to declare the `LastName` as a property.

```
[AdditionalMetadata("VariableName", "VariableValue")]
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

No need to do any changes on the `PartialClasses.cs`.You have to retrieve it correctly on the view as shown below .

```
<h2>
  @ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.LastName, ViewData).AdditionalValues["VariableName"]
</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, however I get the error:
Attribute 'AdditionalMetadata' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, property, indexer, interface' declarations.

Comment: I've added more detail to the original question. Ideally I don't want to edit the Student.cs file (where the property is declared) - as this is autogenerated from my model (which may change). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you're telling ? your matadata property is wrong.you have to declare it as a property.what is the problem there ? you cannot put it as a variable.

Comment: Ah, I was getting confused because I had already declared a get+set for LastName. I've done as you suggested and its working. Many thanks for your help.